# Как заставить Yii2 не использовать md5 для хэширования ключей Redis в классе \yii\redis\Cache?

Tags: yii2, yii, redis

Очень нужно сделать так, чтобы Yii2 использую класс  \yii\redis\Cache не хэшировал имена ключей.

```
// prefix:keyname1 -> 0e46d28d5fb7676bffd12253c26aec56
Yii::$app->cache->set( 'prefix:keyname1', 'key-value-1, 60 * 60 * 24 ); 

// keyname2 -> keyname2 
Yii::$app->cache->set( 'keyname2', 'key-value-2, 60 * 60 * 24 );
```

Суть проблемы заключается в том, что если в названии ключа встречаются символы ':', '@' и т.п. - класс  \yii\redis\Cache захэширует эти имена ключей алгоритмом md5... Как заставить  \yii\redis\Cache не делать этого?

Comment: Переопределить класс и переписать функцию хеширования как вам угодно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно перегрузить метод `buildKey` класса `Cache`.

Например, так (для шаблона basic).

1. Создайте в папке `components` класс `CustomRedisCache`:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace app\components;

   class CustomRedisCache  extends \yii\redis\Cache
   {
       public function buildKey($key)
       {
           return $key; // оставляем ключ как есть
       }
   }
   ```
2. В файле конфигурации используйте этот класс вместо `\yii\redis\Cache`:

   ```
   'components' => [
       'cache' => [
           'class' => 'app\components\CustomRedisCache',
       ],
   ```